# Joomla: which file is taking care of the "logout" action

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I am learning the basic concept of how to manage login process and sessions. I am trying to find out how Joomla 3.4 handles "logout" action to verify whether I have correctly understand what I have learned. But I have trouble finding out which PHP file is actually taking care of the "logout" logic. Here is what I do:

Firstly, I think no matter what fancy library or framework Joomla is using, down to bottom, there should be a file receiving "$_POST" data, so I searched `$_POST` among all PHP files in my site, and I found this file "libraries/legacy/request/request.php" with this function

```
Class JRequest{
    .....
    public static function getVar($name, $default = null, $hash = 'default', $type = 'none', $mask = 0)
    {
        // Ensure hash and type are uppercase
        $hash = strtoupper($hash);

        if ($hash === 'METHOD')
        {
            $hash = strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
        }

        $type = strtoupper($type);
        $sig = $hash . $type . $mask;

        // Get the input hash
        switch ($hash)
        {
            case 'GET':
                $input = &$_GET;
                break;
            case 'POST':
                $input = &$_POST;
                break;
            case 'FILES':
                $input = &$_FILES;
                break;
            case 'COOKIE':
                $input = &$_COOKIE;
                break;
            case 'ENV':
                $input = &$_ENV;
                break;
            case 'SERVER':
                $input = &$_SERVER;
                break;
            default:
                $input = &$_REQUEST;
                $hash = 'REQUEST';
                break;
        }
.....
```

It seems to me Joomla has integrated "$_POST" data processing into this function so whenever Joomla wants to deal with user input, it will call this function. So I continue to search `JRequest::getVar` among all PHP files, I found only 1 occurence, which is in `components/com_meida/views/medialist/view.html.php` line 64

```
$dirname = JRequest::getVar('folder', '', '', 'string');
```

This doesn't look like having anything to do with login/logout processing. So I widen my search to just `getVar`, although there are many occurrences, none of them looks like relevant and this is where I got stuck.

Which PHP file should I be looking for, and what is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify first what Joomla version do you mean.

For Joomla! 3:

For backend:

`/administrator/components/com_login/controller.php` line 85 starts function logout

For frontend:

`plugins/system/logout/logout.php` line 65 function onUserLogout

The user logout is handled here
`components/com_users/controllers/user.php` on line 98

IN example template in `components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default_logout.php`

you can see how it done.. especially that part of code:

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&task=user.logout'); ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal well">
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="icon-arrow-left icon-white"></span> <?php echo JText::_('JLOGOUT'); ?></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base64_encode($this->params->get('logout_redirect_url', $this->form->getValue('return'))); ?>" />
        <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
    </form>
```

As for your approach:
JRequest handles all request variables (POST,GET,REQUEST) so they can be passed trough input filter to be sanitized.

For more information visit https://docs.joomla.org/ to learn how Joomla works... Also for specific Joomla question is better to use the forum - http://forum.joomla.org/ .... also... there is a website on stack exchange called https://joomla.stackexchange.com/ only for joomla questions :)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I am using Joomla 3.4, editted.

Comment: I am expecting that `getVar` function to be called when loging user out, because I think all $_POST Datas are processed by this function, including  that `$_POST` generated when user clicks "logout". But it is not, why is that?

Comment: The documentation page is the first place I went for help, but to be honest, I have to learn much more things before it can be more helpful. Also I think the documentation is incompleted, many basic concepts are not well explained, making it much harder for beginners like me to understand.

Comment: I have updated my answer, as you can see, there are no need for post datas as far as i can see.

Comment: http://nyaii.com/s/form.png Look at this picture, the method of this logout form is "post", so I think when user clicks "logout" button, a global variable should be created, be it $_POST or $_REQUEST

Comment: You are right, you should post this question in joomla.stackexchange.com and delete it here.